# How to store and access uploaded files in a separate partition in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I have a laravel 5.1 app which receives many documents and is used internally in the company. These documents are currently stored in the filesystem in the following directories:

1. corporate_reports
2. job_letters
3. documentations
4. resumes

The above directories are currently in the laravel public folder and the filesystem is /dev/sda. I easily display these documents on the web browser with a code like below:

```
<td>
 <a href="{{  url('corporate_reports/' . HelperClass::extract_year($report->upload_date) .'/'. $report->id .'/'.
                                               $report->name)  }}" target=_blank>View</a>
</td>
```

The problem now is that the filesystem is growing rapidly. I talked to the system admin and he created another partition `/dev/mapper/data-Datos  107G   61M  101G   1% /data`

What we are trying to accomplish now is to upload our files to `/data` instead of the project directory `/var/www/corp.example.com/public_html/public` like below.

1. /data/corporate_reports
2. /data/job_letters
3. /data/documentations
4. /data/resumes

How may I go about this implementation i.e upload the files to this separate partition and then be able to display the document on the web browser. Any user granted access to this system can view any of the above documents?

Comment: You are going to need an Apache `Alias` setup with relevant access rights so that you can place files on the new `/data` folder [See the manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html)

Comment: Just an alternative that might be useful for some. I found AWS S3 buckets to work really well when we encountered this problem. You can then set files to be public or private depending on their use. It was surprisingly fast for us to upload these files https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem